# How do i delete all devices registered under a gateway

Tags: java, watson-iot

I have a server that acts as a gateway for devices that would like to publish data to the IoT Platform, but can't do so directly using the DeviceClient.  I would like to start from a fixed known state when the server starts up and be as resilient as possible to server crashes.

Devices are only able to publish when the server is up so I should be able to always start with a single gateway registered for the server on IoT, no devices associated with the gateway and create new devices as they contact the server.

I can delete the gateway using the deleteDevice() api,

> api().deleteDevice(deviceType, deviceId);

but how do I find all the devices (device ids) created under the gateway so I delete them with something like the above code?  I have a shared platform, so I can't just delete all devices of a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API call that get devices that are connected through the gateway specified by id {deviceId}, this is the one:

https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/apis/swagger/v0002/org-admin.html#!/Device_Configuration/get_device_types_typeId_devices_deviceId_devices

You can start from there. The same api call should be available on the library you are using.

Comment: I think you're suggesting that device type id is used to get the devices for a gateway, but I can't do that since multiple servers, each assigned a different gateway, use the same type id.  I'd rather not use different type ids for each gateway instance.

Comment: device type id is required for identification, but the removal is taken over deviceId